# How to scale 2d world with 3d rendering?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using 3d mode to render my 2d game, because the camera rotation and zooming in/out is much easier than with 2d mode.

Now i have ran into a problem i cant seem to think how to fix:

- How to make the 2d plane of my world to fit the screen in a way that 1 texture pixel matches 1 pixel on my screen? In other words: how do i calculate the z-position of my camera to achieve this?

My texcoords start from 0 and ends to 1, so i can see all the pixels from one tile in the GL_NEAREST texture filter mode.

My window is resizeable in a way that my tiles are always squares but the visible area expands depending on how i resize my window.

**Edit:** my view port is using perspective mode, not isometric. but if its not possible in perspective mode, im willing to change to isometric.

Answer (score 2):

Use an orthographic projection that maps eye space units to pixels:

```
glViewport(0,0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);
```

#### Update due to question update:

A texel → viewport pixel matching is possible with a perspective projection, but only under a certain constraint: The textured quad must be coplanar to the perspective frustum near/far plane.

How to do it? For `glFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)` with Z=near, XY eye space range [left, right]×[bottom, top] maps to NDC xy[-1, 1]² and NDC xy[-1, 1]² maps to the viewport extents. So those are all affine transformations following the law

```
y(x) = to_lower_bound + (x - from_lower_bound) * (to_upper_bound - to_lower_bound) / (from_upper_bound - from_lower_bound)
```

All you have to do it map viewport to NDC to near plane and if you're Z =/= near scale by near/Z.

Comment: How about with perspective mode?

Comment: Why would you use a perspective view matrix if you want a 1:1 mapping from screen pixels to world units?

Comment: If you are only drawing 2D why would you use perspective mode?

Comment: @Ron, i might want to skew the view a little bit... not sure yet. and out of interest i would like to know how to do it both ways as well.

Comment: something is wrong with this code... it crashes my program somehow (i start to hear beep inside my computer case when i try to click in the program, and CPU usage goes skyhigh, SCARY!). but i managed to make it work with my own old code... but now i ran into problem how to determine which area of the screen i am currently seeing (my current perspective render mode code doesnt seem to work with isometric render mode). or maybe i messed up something myself. edit: checked my code... cant really understand why it freezes like that... the working code of my uses different values for parameters.

Comment: also, this solution isnt an answer to the problem of determining the z-pos... still unsolved mystery.

Comment: @Rookie: The z-position doesn't matter in ortho mode, because it doesn't scale things. Use it to layer things.

Comment: @Rookie: If your system gets the frenzy if using ortho projection, something is really messed up. Please post your code somewhere.

Comment: Are you aware im using 3d render mode...? i understand that in 2d render mode i dont care about the z-position. im still trying to figure the correct z-position to either make 1:1, 2:1, 3:1 etc scaled textures. your code doesnt help on that. btw, did you try to run your code yourself? i think you have parameters in wrong order and thats why the freeze. (also you missed to add glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) and glLoadIdentity() in the end)

Comment: @Rookie: OpenGL doesn't distinct between 3D and 2D mode. All it does is pushing vectors through matrices. Also I've used that code hundreds of times. Geesh, this is part of the OpenGL API I know by heart and never have to look up the specs. In fact I even can write the underlying matrices out of my head. If something broke it's definitely not this tame code snippet, that, in worst case would make things not appear on your screen if it was wrong.

Comment: @Rookie: And no, I didn't forget to switch to glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) at the end. I just omitted it. And BTW, because you're obviously a total newbie: If you see a tutorial the sets the projection matrix in the window resize handler, don't follow it. The projection matrix, like all other drawing related state, should be set in the drawing handler (together with viewport, depth testing mode, clear colors and so on).

Comment: this is my render loop: glClear(), setviewport() (with the extra 2 commands i gave here), render_model(), swap_buffers(). "that, in worst case would make things not appear on your screen if it was wrong", thats exactly what it did, but with the freeze. edit: if you know im a total newb, i can say, i am. and i missed 99% of your edited question for that reason. i have never used glFrustum() and i dont understand why do i need to use it now, when the only problem is that i need to find the z-pos. finding the z-pos then allows me to adjust z-pos which results into zoom in/out effect.

Comment: @Rookie: A full non-/working code example posted at pastebin.com or similar would help: I can test it myself and identify any problems. Or I just might see problematic parts immediately.